# main.go:11:8: package aerospike_shared is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/aerospike_shared)

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I've been searching for the whole day what's happening in here and it's seems to be it should work without a problem according to Docker and golang documentation.

**First of all the error:**

```
holms@debian ~/D/c/s/app-prebid-config> compose -f compose.yml build app-prebid-config
Building app-prebid-config
Step 1/11 : FROM golang:1.14-alpine as dev
 ---> 51e47ee4db58
Step 2/11 : RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add --no-cache bash git
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8ddb9b995df8
Step 3/11 : RUN mkdir -p /app/prebid-config
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4c1e8f03b27c
Step 4/11 : WORKDIR /app/prebid-config
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 25104c791d7e
Step 5/11 : RUN go mod init setupad.com/prebid-config
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0b64b735c1f1
Step 6/11 : RUN go mod download
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7170aa6447c9
Step 7/11 : RUN go mod vendor
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0bbc220e43b9
Step 8/11 : COPY . .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9d5ab625ccd0
Step 9/11 : RUN go get -d -v ./...
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d4057dd0d9a7
Step 10/11 : RUN go install -v ./...
 ---> Running in c5b7a8cbc33e
main.go:11:8: package aerospike_shared is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/aerospike_shared)
ERROR: Service 'app-prebid-config' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c go install -v ./...' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
holms@debian ~/D/c/s/a/app> cat Dockerfile 
FROM golang:1.14-alpine as dev

ENV GO111MODULE=auto
ENV CGO_ENABLED=0
ENV GOOS=linux

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add --no-cache bash git

RUN mkdir -p /app/prebid-config
WORKDIR /app/prebid-config

COPY go.mod  .
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN go get -d -v ./...
RUN go install -v ./...
RUN go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app .

FROM alpine:latest as prod
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
COPY --from=dev /app/app /app
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["/app"]
```

**Code it self:**

```
holms@debian ~/D/c/s/a/app> tree
.
├── aerospike_shared
│   └── client.go
├── Dockerfile
└── main.go

1 directory, 3 files
```

**main.go**

```
holms@debian ~/D/c/s/a/app> cat main.go
package main

import (
        "net/http"

        "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
        "github.com/labstack/echo/v4/middleware"
        "github.com/labstack/gommon/log"
)

import "aerospike_shared"

func main() {

        // Echo instance
        e := echo.New()
        e.Logger.SetLevel(log.ERROR)
        e.Use(middleware.Logger())

        e.GET("/", func(c echo.Context) error {
                return c.String(http.StatusOK, "Hello, World!")
        })

        // Connect to Aerospike
        a = aerospike_shared.client

        // Start server
        e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":1323"))
}
```

**aerospike_shared/client.go**

```
holms@debian ~/D/c/s/a/app> cat aerospike_shared/client.go
package aerospike_shared

import (
        "bytes"
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "math"
        "os"
        "runtime"
        "strconv"

        as "github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go"
)

var WritePolicy = as.NewWritePolicy(0, 0)
var Policy = as.NewPolicy()

var Host = os.Getenv("AEROSPIKE_HOST")
var Port, PortErr = strconv.Atoi(os.Getenv("AEROSPIKE_PORT"))

var Namespace = "prebid"
var Set = "prebid_configs"

var client *as.Client

func main() {
        // use all cpus in the system for concurrency
        runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())

        log.SetOutput(os.Stdout)

        var err error
        client, err = as.NewClient(Host, Port)
        if err != nil {
                PanicOnError(err)
        }
}

func PanicOnError(err error) {
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalln(err.Error())
        }
}
```

Comment: Please read How to Write Go Code and stick to it. You cannot use import "aerospike_shared" likes this. Use Go modules.

Comment: Seems to be all I've needed is a full path. But no one is documenting WHAT IS a full path, except that there's remote urls for some reason, and I don't intend to store this in public VCS at all. Full path is just project name and folder in it. So basically `go mod init mypackage` and then `import mypackage/aerospike_shared` that's it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've read official docs and 5 blog posts and couldn't find how to use relative modules.

So mistake is that I haven't been using full path. But I couldn't find anywhere defined what is a full path. Golang documentation a full of imports with remote url's and I won't even store this code remotely at all.

For relative path to work you need to use your project name for full path. So just do `go mod init mypackage` and then in the code it would `import "mypackage/aerospike_shared` and it will work.

Comment: The import path mypackage/aerospike is not a relative import path. Relative import paths are paths starting with "./" or "../" . Also: An import path of the form "something.other.foo/xyz/bar" is not pers se a "remote" URL. It is just an import path.

Comment: @Volker so would be nice to use non-url paths if possible, as it's highly confusing. Anyway at least it compiles fine now and more readable for me :) Also learned that using underscore in package name seems to be not recommended, so using dashes.